# VLOOKUP Formula Sought - My One Isn't Working

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hey so I'm looking for a VLOOKUP formula which compares an old database of name and email to a new one and then spits out the first names next to the emails for the new database. In the new database I just have emails. The new database has 20k emails and the old one has 50k with names. I want only the cleaned database to have names from the old database next to them.

The columns are as follow:

B:B is all the new emails, G:G is all the old emails, H:H are all the names.

I'm trying =VLOOKUP(A:A,G:H,H:H) but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: try vlookup(lookup_value,index_array,result_column_number,0) ie vlookup(a1,g1:h200,2,0)

Comment: Thanks Mike, still spits out a N/A result.

Comment: Does it matter if I have labels on the columns or not? Because I don't

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/seIRJxk  ok so i've cleaned it up further - here's the issue. I'm looking at Column A, which is the new list. Then I have F and G which was emails and names. So in perhaps Column D, I'd like to just pull the names that correspond to the emails in Column A from Column G. Maybe this'll help you further. Thanks!

Comment: Show a sample of each data set in your question, as I can’t guess, but have given you the correct vlookup syntax. That image is very poor. If your index column is on the right, then vlookup won’t work. A combination of index() and match() will but need a decent image to see.

Comment: Hey Mike, give this one a go. The A column is the new emails, I'm trying to get it to compare the emails and names from F and G and just return the names from G that correspond to A and display them in D. Hope this helps. https://imgur.com/a/ErGP7Mj

Answer (score 0):

Try *vlookup(A1,F1:G50000,2,0)*

I think that should do the job if you put the formula in cell B1

Comment: Nice one Domo, think we have a winner! Thanks

Comment: scratch that, try  vlookup(A1,$F$1:$G$50000,2,0)    ...need to lockdown the lockdown the table array or you will get some errors returned to you. My apologies.